# HTTP test server accepting image data like jpg with POST request

Tags: json, http, post

I need a test server for **http POST command**, which can receive **image** like jpg, png; display it or at lest it can show that my device send image via POST command success.
Is there any server like that ready for the test?

Comment: httpbin.org may be useful.  Not sure what you mean by "display it", however.

Comment: I know the server can respond with the content the device send from POST command, but what about it can display that content on the server website, in my case it's a file image?